# Запятая в БСП с нетипичными отношениями между частями

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, бсп

В Интернете один популярный молодой редактор, который пишет в довольно разговорном стиле, в статьях постоянно использует запятую там, где, по моему мнению, ей совсем не место.

Примеры:

> 1. *Это ерунда, так нельзя*.

Правильно: *Это ерунда. Так нельзя*.

> 2. *Лаборатория занимается контролем качества, тоже плюс*.

Правильно: *Лаборатория занимается контролем качества, — тоже плюс*.

> 3. *Здесь про уютные дома, мне это интересно*.

Правильно: *Здесь про уютные дома. Мне это интересно*.

> 4. *Автор не может знать все о теме, этого и не требуется*.

Правильно: *Автор не может знать все о теме. Этого и не требуется*.

Или так, если неожиданное присоединение: *Автор не может знать все о теме — этого и не требуется*.

Во всех примерах простые предложения в составе сложного не связаны отношениями перечисления (одновременности либо последовательности), а это единственное условие, при котором ставится запятая.

**Вопрос**. Является ли такое употребление запятой ошибочным? Или можно допустить авторский замысел передать непрерывность мысли, которая точкой или другими знаками была бы прервана, разделена?

Answer (score 1):

Не является ошибкой.

Автор принимает решение о том, как комбинировать простые предложения в тексте.

Более того, оригинальные варианты с запятой лучше. Причина запятых в том, что это законченная мысль. Предложения читаются на одном дыхании и выражают одну идею. Нет веских причин, чтобы разделять точкой.

Точка только мешает, если выражается одна мысль.

Примеры:

*Здесь про уютные дома, мне это интересно. --- Данная тема интересна.*

*Это ерунда, так нельзя. --- Это плохо.*

Автор не может знать все о теме, этого и не требуется. --- Знание всего о теме не требуется.

Во втором примере действительно лучше с тире, так как можно вставить "это".

Answer (score 1):

Вы говорите: "Во всех примерах простые предложения в составе сложного не связаны отношениями **перечисления** (одновременности либо последовательности), а это **единственное условие, при котором ставится запятая**".

**Но это неверно.** Перечислительные отношения возможны только в БСП **однородного состава**, а есть еще **неоднородные БСП**. Во всех приведенных предложениях запятая может  быть поставлена, так как простые предложения в составе БСП **неоднородные**, а отношения между ними **распространительно-присоединительные**.

В этом случае может использоваться и запятая, и тире, что зависит от длительности паузы. В таких предложениях  интонация практически такая же, как и при делении их на отдельные предложения, только пауза практически отсутствует. Это позволяет не делить сложное предложение на два простых, если они тесно связаны по смыслу. **Как раз такое деление и кажется стилистически некорректным.**

**Так что к автору нет претензий,** а вот ваши правила вызывают сомнения. Например:

*Лаборатория занимается контролем качества, — тоже плюс.* Почему использован такой *серьезный* единый знак "запятая и тире", характерный в основном для сложных конструкций? Здесь простого тире вполне достаточно, да и запятую можно поставить, если стиль разговорный.

*Автор не может знать все о теме, этого и не требуется.* Тире можно поставить, но зачем требовать для этого  *неожиданного присоединения*, присоединение здесь самое обычное.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, правило, в котором сказано об употреблении запятой в **БСП неоднородного состава** — насколько мне известно по классическим справочникам по пунктуации, употребляется только двоеточие, тире и запятая и тире как единый знак. Да, есть некоторые исключения: *Слышу, земля задрожала* (пояснение); *Допрошу его осторожно, он и не заметит*; *Человек не иголка, найдём*. Возможно, последние два чем‑то напоминают наши примеры. Просто я ориентируюсь на § 43 у Розенталя: "Запятая и точка с запятой в бессоюзном сложном предложении".

Comment: *"Лаборатория занимается контролем качества, — тоже плюс". Почему использован такой серьезный единый знак "запятая и тире", характерный в основном для сложных конструкций?*

"Запятая и тире часто ставятся в бессоюзном сложном предложении перед словом это или вот, начинающим присоединительное предложение: *Эдгар По считается отличным мастером формы, оригинальным художником, — это бесспорно* (М. Г.)". *Лаборатория занимается контролем качества, — [это] тоже плюс*.

Comment: Это не наш пример. Вы обратили внимание, что в первом предложении однородные члены? Если не поставить единый знак, то присоединение  будет относится только к последнему однородному члену. Так что здесь этот знак необходим.

Comment: В правилах Розенталя  о тире и двоеточии в БСП постоянно встречаются замечания о том, что эти знаки  зависят от интонации и вместо них может ставится запятая. Это как раз касается неоднородной связи в БСП, когда второе предложение просто распространяет первое без указания на конкретные отношения. (Информация о видах БСП в ответе взята из вузовской грамматики).

Comment: Примечание. При отсутствии предупредительной интонации двоеточие "в этих случаях не ставится: Сейчас не поедешь, жарко (Ч.).Примечание. При отсутствии оттенка предупреждения в начале бессоюзного сложного предложения данного типа после первой части вместо двоеточия ставится запятая: Слышу, земля задрожала (Н.).Примечания: 1. Если значение следствия интонационно не подчеркивается, то вместо тире между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится запятая: …Я допрошу его осторожно, он и не заметит (Ч.); Человек не иголка, найдём (Ч.).

Comment: Попробуйте скачать  учебник для вузов Кустова и др "Синтаксис современного  русского языка". Я пользуюсь этой книгой (правда, у меня издание 2013 года, один автор и называется "Курс лекций", но содержание  в оглавлении похоже). Правила  пунктуации основаны на грамматике, но изучать грамматику лучше по специальной литературе.  Там есть информация о различных видах БСП. https://alleng.org/d/rusl/rusl629.htm

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю)